# How quickly does air return to a vacuum chamber?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, forces, soft-question

I know there are a lot of variables that affect how quickly this would occur. Any information on the topic would be highly appreciated. For sake of argument, lets say 1 square foot chamber, lets say medium vacuum, and a 1/16 square inch opening.
If you could provide me with any formulas or thoughts on the topic that would be very helpful.

Also, how would the speed change with a different gas, say hydrogen? Or even, a liquid such as water?

Thanks

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12580/

Comment: A chamber with a vacuum in it would have a volume, not an area - 1 cubic foot. Why don't you state your pressure, say 1/10 atm. Is your opening round or square?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but can you explain the relevance?

Comment: LDC3 - yeah mistake on area/volume. Square opening and it would be 1/100 (.01) atm. Thanks

Comment: Martin, can you explain how I can apply that thread to a situation with a vacuum?

Comment: The pressure difference is just 1 atm in the case of vacuum and depends on the height of the water in the other case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I depends on the pressure ratio between the chamber and ambient . As long as the ratio is *critical*, the ambient air will flow through the orifice at the speed of sound (with respect to the state in the chamber). For *undercritical* pressure ratio the flow can basically be found by the Bernoulli Equation.

Comment: How would I know if it were critical? I'm assuming that under most circumstances it would not be critical.

Comment: A short introduction is given for example here http://www.thermopedia.com/content/267/?tid=104&sn=1297